# Getting Error regarding Solr after upgrading sitecore from 7.2 to 7.5

Tags: solr, sitecore, upgrade, sitecore7.2, sitecore7.5

I am getting error on all pages after i upgraded the sitecore 7.2 system to Sitecore 7.5

> Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Method 'get_IsSharded' in type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex' from assembly 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_IsSharded' in type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex' from assembly 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Source Error: 


Line 80:             string fullTextQuery = "", List<Refinement> refinementFilter = null,
Line 81:             List<PrioritizedField> overrideContentPrioritizedFieldList = null)
Line 82:         {
Line 83:             var query = GetQueryableResults(indexName, language, templateGuidFilter, locationGuidFilter, fullTextQuery, refinementFilter, overrideContentPrioritizedFieldList);
Line 84:             return query != null ? query.Select(toItem => toItem.GetItem()).ToList() : null;
```

Any Help regarding this would be appreciated

Comment: Have you downloaded and extracted dlls for the 7.5 solr support package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to have missed upgrading Solr support Package, Based on what version of 7.5 you have upgraded, you need to go CMS [Updates Page](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/Update.aspx) and go to "Download the Solr support package" section and upgrade the dlls.

Comment: Thanks for that, now it is showing another error "Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/databasePropertyStore"

Comment: @ShabeerThalaprathu Did you upgrade Content Search configurations files? You need to follow steps in https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/xdb_upgrade_and_conversion_guide_sc75-a4.pdf

And upgrade all Content search related configs, like Sitecore.ContentSearch.config and Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Indexes** files

Comment: @ShabeerThalaprathu Also, what is the release version of 7.5 that you have upgraded to?

Comment: I have updated to latest one (150212), I am able to Solve this issue, The entry was missing in config file,  Now I am getting an error   
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.RequiredObjectIsNullException: Could not find add method: AddCopyField (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)

Comment: @ShabeerThalaprathu I would advice you to download the Solr package again from https://sdn.sitecore.net/downloads/SitecoreSolrSupport100rev150116.download and extract the dll files (bin) again, then copy them to your bin. and also extract the Config files (App_Config\Include) and merge them with what you have.

Comment: I did what did you told, But i am facing some config values issues,   "Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore". If you see in new config files in solr support, you will not be able to find these node, Please let me know if you have some idea on this.

Comment: Backup all of your Sitecore.ContentSearch.* config files, then add new ones from fresh installation (This includes also Solr configs), If this works, you need to compare your files and see what you have missed in the upgrade